# Idiom to describe something that is 'Just Right'

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-requests, titles

I am doing an English Project and am trying to decide for a title. I am analysing movie which I thought was really well done, and hence was trying to decide on an idea for the article I am writing.

I came across the phrase 'Just the right amount of everything', since the movie was all-round well done and had great features without being too over-done. However, I want something a little more catchy to readers. After doing a bit of research I came across the Swedish word 'Lagom', which means exactly what I what I was aiming for. However, it is unfortunately in a different language which is a little annoying...

Can anyone suggest a similar idiom or catchy phrase that could be used in this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: 'Goldilocks' springs to mind (from the fairy tale in which the little girl finds Baby Bear's things 'just right' for her). See https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/goldilocks

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, that is another idea that sprung to mind as well. Now then, how to implement this as a catchy title that people will want to read? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You could say the movie “hits all the right notes”.

Answer (score 1):

I think Kate Bunting's answer is a hard one to beat but I'm suggesting another word all the same.

Pitch-perfect

: Striking exactly the right note or tone: “He spoke beautiful English, spiced with pitch-perfect sarcasm” (Michael Finkel).

American Heritage Dictionary

Comment: Yes, that's certainly a decent idea. The only problem I thought of was that pitch-perfect more refers to a certain 'pitch or tone' rather than something as a whole (i.e. a movie). Do you have any idea how this could be used as a title? Equally, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: ["The political newcomer launched and led a pitch-perfect race over the summer."
— Mattie Kahn ]                      
I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean by "refers to a certain 'pitch or tone' rather than something as a whole." And your question doesn't specify if it's the title to your piece that you want or something else?

Comment: Yes it's a title that I want. By the certain 'pitch or tone', I am referring to the idiom itself. A _pitch_ refers to 'a sound governed by the vibrations producing it', and this word 'pitch' is the basis for which this idiom is formed. Thus, it could be assumed that in correct usage, 'pitch-perfect' would normally be used in a phrase related to sound. E.g. A pitch-perfect musical recital.

Comment: I appended a second example sentence above just to illustrate that you need not constrain a word to its most general meaning.  Rest, coming up with a suitable title calls for having gone over what you have written. Good luck! :)